# How do I properly tune parameters for a neural network?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization

How do I tune the parameters for a neural network such as the amount of layers, the types of layers, the width, etc.?  Right now I simply guess for good parameters.  This becomes very expensive and time consuming for me as I will tune a network and then find out that it didn't do any better than the previous model.  Is there better way to tune the model to get a good test and validation score?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally hit and trail method. You have to play around it. There is no particular method to do that. Try to use GPU instead to CPU to compute fast such as **"Google Colab"**. My suggestion is note down all the parameters that can be tunned.
eg:

> 1. **Optimizer**: Try to use different optimizer such as Adam,SGD,many more
> 2. **learning rate** : This is a very crucial parameter, try to change it from .0001 to 0.001 step by 0.0001.
> 3. **Number of hidden layers** : Try to increase no. of hidden layers.
> 4. Try to use **Batch Normalization** or **Drop out** or both if required.
> 5. Use correct **Loss funtion**.
> 6. Change **Batch size** and **Epoch**.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden layers, Epochs, batch-size: Try different numbers.

Optimizers: Adam (gives better results), Rmsprop

Dropout: 0.2 works well in most case

Also as a plus, you should also try different activation functions ( like you can use ReLu in the hidden layers and for output layer use sigmoid for binary class classification and softmax for multiclass classification.